# Django can't get function from one view to another view

Tags: django, python-2.7

I got two view files(let it be view1 and view2) in same application. There function in view1
appcard, that I tried to improt in view2,

```
from app.view1 import appcard
```

but got error

```
cannot import name appcard
```

Is there way to solve this problem?ALready tryed to import whole viev file, but got another error , somthing like "appcard not defined".

```
view1.py
...
def appcard(request,exte):
    """some code"""
    return render(request,
        'app/applicantcard.html',
    )


view2.py
from app.view1 import appcard

def applicant_home(request):
    exte='applicant/applicant_layout.html'
    return appcard(request, exte)
```

If

```
from .view1 import appcard
```

there are error:

```
ImportError at /
cannot import name appcard
```

Comment: Try `from . view1 import appcard` if the files are in the same folder. Note the dot for relative import!

Comment: When you say two views, do you mean two `views.py` files or two views? What is the full error you get?

Comment: there are two views :
views and applicant_views

ImportError at /
cannot import name appcard

Comment: From the error it seems you are trying to import the function `applicantcard` . Is this the name of the function in `view1` which you want imported?

Comment: my typo. error is cannot import name appcard

Comment: add related source code of file and also structure of your app please

Comment: A couple of obvious points... sorry if you've checked already. Do you have an `__init__.py` in your appcard directory? And have you tried removing all .pyc files with `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete` (shouldn't matter but just in case!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import a something from a module (file) in the same package (folder) you should use the relative import notation - using the dot. In your case use:

```
from .view1 import appcard
```

It also seems you have a typo in your code: first you say you have in the `view1` file the function `appcatd` and the you try to import `appcard`. So you should import the exact name of the function.

Comment: typo in question sorry.Tryed from . view1 import appcard, still not worked

Comment: it's `from .view1 import appcard` just remove that space.

Comment: ...space is typo...from .view1 import appcard  still not working

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it was actualy totall mess: I imported some function from view2 to view1,that uses function that uses some imported from view1 function. Sorry,rearranged functions and now its working fine.

Comment: It's called a circular import. Basically you imported the other module while the first is being loaded, it tries to import the first module, at that time the function doesn't exist yet.